# Prase string and save it as key value pair

Tags: java

I want to parse this string and get values based on key and value like application_id is key and 123456 is its value.
Please help in java code

```
String testString ="\"application_id\":\"123456\",\"application_name\":\"Shitanshu / Train ticket book\",\"appstore_id\":\"89\",\"appstore_name\":\"Google Play Store\",\"version\":\"1.1\",\"rating\":\"5\",\"title\":\"null\",\"comment\":\"Really fast recharge.... N the repayments are also really fast...\",\"user\":\"narasimham sai\",\"date\":\"2014-07-29\",\"time\":\"20:53:34\",\"iso_code\":\"null\",\"country_name\":\"null\",\"labels\":\"[]\"";
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What have you tried so far? One long line of code does not a question make: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I want to parse this string and get values based on key and value like application_id is key and 123456 is its value.

Comment: Please improve this question. Please clearly state the language you are using, what your objectives are, what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Sounds like you should use `,` as delimiter and then `:` delimiter in the result

Comment: Hi, have a read of [How to create a short, self contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/). Show us what you have done so far, what effort you have made, what errors or unexpected outputs you may have. `Give me teh c0dez` is not on topic here. Freelancer or Rent a Coder will do that for a fair market price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the string on `,`, split the pairs on `:`:

```
Map<String, String> theMap = new HashMap<>();
String[] pairs = testString.split(",");
for (String pair : pairs) {
    String[] parts = pair.replaceAll("\"", "").split(":");
    theMap.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
}

System.out.println(theMap.get("application_id"));
```

Output:

```
123456
```